# how can i change dbeaver preference unpinned tabs close automatically?

Tags: dbeaver

in dbeaver, when i execute sql, editor does not close previous result tabs automatically. (ıt should be a preference for this?) How can the edior close unpinned result tabs automatically?

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Could you please clarify it a bit more

Comment: For example, 1) when i executed this statement like select * from table1 , a result tab showed up )       2)  when i executed another statement like select from table2, first result tab stayed and anohter result tab showed up. (i  just expect  editor close previous result tab when i execute new sql statement.

Comment: So in a sense your requirement is to have a single Result tab which shows all the results for all the queries that you do. Am I right?

Comment: whenever i execute different query on same editor page, i expect previous result tab to be closed.

Comment: Which execute button are you using?We do have two buttons right. One for producing output on the same Result Tab and the other for producing output on a new tab

Comment: ctrl+enter  (execute sql statement - orange run button